# Change events on click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Given a list of elements, I want to switch each one between 2 states (i.e., 0 and 1). Clicking a 0 will change it to 1 and vice versa.

In addition, I want to reset the rest of elements to 0 or 1 given the case.

Here's what I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```
 <html>
        <ul>
            <li id="A1">Im a 0</li>
            <li id="A2">Im a 0</li>
            <li id="A3">Im a 0</li>
            <li id="A4">Im a 0</li>
            <li id="A5">Im a 0</li>

            <li id="B1">Im a 1</li>
            <li id="B2">Im a 1</li>
            <li id="B3">Im a 1</li>
            <li id="B4">Im a 1</li>
            <li id="B5">Im a 1</li>
        </ul>
    </html>
```

**Script :**

```
$("[id^=B]").hide();


$("[id^=A]").click(function(){ 

      var switcha;

      switcha=$(this).attr("id").substr(1);
      alert(switcha);
      $(this).fadeOut(100);
      $("#B"+switcha).delay(100).fadeIn(100);

});

$("[id^=B]").click(function(){ 

      var switchb;

      switchb=$(this).attr("id").substr(1);
      $(this).fadeOut(100);
      $("#A"+switchb).delay(100).fadeIn(100);

});

</script>
```

This works for each element (they become 0 or 1 on click), but I don't know how to reset the rest of the IDs, so they become 0 or 1 given the previous click on each individual ID.

Sorry if it is messy; can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can u please explain more clearly. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @syedimty He has two sections of code When he clicks on a **Im a 0** he want's to hide it and show the corresponding 0 element by Id Like `A1 to B1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite unclear what you wish to achieve.. If you want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuPkC/

Or You want this:

http://jsfiddle.net/kGeJ7/

Else you can replace the following code in the second fiddle

```
$("[id^=B]").click(function(){ 

      var switchb;

    $(".B").hide();  
    $(".A").show();
      switchb=$(this).attr("id").substr(1);
      $(this).fadeOut(100);
      $("#A"+switchb).delay(100).fadeIn(100);

});
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot. Second fiddle link was exactly what i was trying to do. Thanks! :D

Comment: Glad that it helped... :) Don't forget to add reps and select the best answer dude (Whichever you found helpful).. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on the code, since you seem to know how to write it.

But usually, the logic goes like this:

1. Reset All states
2. Switch the state you're on now

So you perform the reset first, to ALL elements, then after switch the state of the required element.

I think that's what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: That's exactly what i was trying to accomplish.

Comment: @RodoR great. If you feel the question has been answered you can choose a best answer by pressing the tick button.